# Grails domain object looks like saved persistently but actually is not

Tags: grails, persistence

I met a situation when I am unable to save certain objects persistently. The objects look like successfully saved ones but later I cannot find them in DB. There is no errors or notifications appearing in console (usually they do on errors). What that could be?

```
// inside a transactioned service method
def m1 = new Merchant(...)
assert m1.save()                // ok
assert m1.id                    // got some good id
assert Merchant.findById(m1.id) // it fails o_O
```

Other objects are saved normally.

Grails 2.1.1, some Oracle

Comment: when you say "cannot find them in DB" you mean by directly querying the DB (via TOAD or whatever you're using), right?

Comment: I cannot find new object nor in DB manager, nor by findById() as in my code.

Comment: to make sure the above code is understood: mi.save() does indeed returns an instance (and doesn't go into the block shortened with elipses above)?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't go into braces. I've removed them for clearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate will typically only flush objects to the database at the end of a session.  Flush the session manually with `sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()` or save the object with `m1.save(flush: true)` to force the object to be written out before the session is done.

Comment: except that doing a findBy* will force a session flush.

Comment: Fine, `session.flush()` just works! Although it is very confusing that objects couldn't be saved in rare cases without any notification... Probably there is a conflict between transactions.